# react-native navigation from child rerenders parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm new with react-native development, and I do not really understand what happens under the hood when using navigation.navigate.

So I have a basic component that displays a list of items using FlatList, and when clicking on an ListCard I want to go to the detail view of that item. I noticed if the list had many items the navigation was a bit slow due to all cards where re-rendered when navigating.

The renderItem handled navigation to another screen, so I thought maybe it changed state "under the hood" and that's why the parent re-rendered and that causes all children to re-render.

So I created a separate file <Child {...props }/> and then inside of this file I handle the navigation (outside of the parent). But each time I navigate from the child I get "Parent rerender" and then all children "I rerender")

```
export const Parent = () => {
   const [alotofItems, setAlotOfItems] = useState<AlotOfItems[]>([])
   console.log("Parent rerender")
   return <FlatList renderItems={({item}) => <Child item={item} />} 
 
}

export const Child = (props) => {
   const navigation = useNavigation()
   console.log("I rerender")
   return <ListCard onPress={() => navigation.navigate(DETAIL_CARD)} />
}
```

If I change so I don't use navigation.navigate and instead go like this, everything works as expected. Only one console.log from the child I actually clicked. What is going wrong, or is this how react-navigation works? How can I overcome this issue?

```
export const Child = (props) => {
   const [openDetail, setOpenDetail] = useState(false)

    console.log("I rerender")

    return ( 
      <>
        {openDetail && <DetailCard /> }
         <ListCard onPress={() => setOpenDetail(true} />
      </>
 )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `Child` component in a `React.memo` higher-order component and use `useNavigation` from there?

Comment: Yes, that works. But is that not expensive? I have 5 tabs, all of them displays a list of items, and when clicking I go into the detail view.

Is it normal to actually navigate into detail-views in react-native? When navigting through tabs I have a header which holds title, notifications icon and a user icon and at the bottom the navbar) but when going into the detail view it just hols the header + detail page.

Maybe I should make a wrapper-component which holds header and you pass it the child (detail-page) so I can open it without navigation, or is that against react-native practices?